# CSS positioning issue with Safari when using :before

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm having an issue when trying to position :before content in Safari. In Chrome/IE the content is positioned correctly, but Safari is interpreting the styles differently (see: http://jsfiddle.net/danwoods/Yb8aR/). my initial thought was to remove the `position: absolute` from the span:before, but that presents it's own issues...

Does anything look out of place? Any explanation as to why Safari is displaying things differently than Chrome?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what problems you were having with removing position absolute, but I've changed it to `position: relative`, used `top: 4px` to line it up with the text, and `display: inline-block` to allow margin right to separate it from the text.

```
span:before {
    content: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6114719/progress-2.png);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Yb8aR/5/ - tested in Chrome and Safari.

**Note:** 
Looks like Safari aligns the before pseudo-element to the span element, whereas Chrome seems to align it to the text within the span element (which is centered).  Why that happens, I'm really not sure.

Comment: That's it. Perfect. I wonder if that's documented anywhere (Safari pseudo-element alignment vs the way Chrome does it)? Thank you...